# VB Script Runtime error 800A01A8 Error Object Required

Tags: file-io, vbscript, runtime-error

I am trying to write a vbs to copy the latest modified files to another location. The script goes like this

```
Option Explicit
Dim oFSO, oFolder, oFile
Dim vSourcePaths ,vDestinationPaths

vSourcePaths = "C:\xampp\htdocs\lgmsuploads"
vDestinationPaths = "S:\LGMSUPLOADS"

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(vSourcePaths)

For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
    If oFile.DateLastModified < DateAdd("h", -24, Now) Then
        oFSO.CopyFile vSourcePaths & "\" & oFile.Name, vDestinationPaths & "\" & oFile.Name                       
    End If
Next
```

But this gives the following error

[image: Error Message]

Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Set` statement to assign an object reference to a variable as follows:

```
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(vSourcePaths)
```

However, your script will copy files with `oFile.DateLastModified` 24 hours ago and before.

Comment: Exactly I have modified the condition so as to copy files of last 24 hours